# How to measure and obtain consistent fps from camera

Tags: python, c++, opencv, camera, frame-rate

My problem is that the frame rate I'm measuring is unstable. I'm trying to save 100 frames with dimensions 2048 x 2448 at 25 fps with a Chameleon3 camera from FLIR, previously Point Grey. With their PyCapture2 module, I'm recording images and saving to computer. It's important to me that I can confirm that I'm recording at 25fps. I want to ask you what's the most reliable way to do that and I want to make sure that I understand what's going on. When I record with the program the camera's shipped with FlyCapture, I measure the time it takes to save the image to disk.

If there's something inaccurate in how I'm phrasing my questions, please let me know.

Is the fastest way to save at a reliable frame rate to store a video in the RAM buffer, in this case 100 frames will be in RAM, and then save the buffer to disk?

I'm thinking that the measured frame rate is unstable because of the time it takes to write the image to the disk. Is this reasonable?

Is there a way to confirm that the video saved into the buffer is the expected framerate?

Sometimes the computer measures that it saves the video at 25fps, and other times at 15fps. Why doesn't the computer save at the same speed every time?

I'm doing this in windows and I tried monitoring the resource monitor during the video recording. The disk read/write spikes to 100%. The RAM isn't filling up.

```
cam = PyCapture2.Camera()
cam.connect(bus.getCameraFromIndex(0))

logging.info('Starting capture...')
cam.startCapture()  # saves to buffer
framerate = 25
save_video_helper(cam, N, filename.encode('utf-8'), framerate, props)
cam.stopCapture()
cam.disconnect()

def save_video_helper(cam, num_images, filename, framerate, props=None, file_format='AVI'):
    video = PyCapture2.FlyCapture2Video()
    if props is not None:
        camera_props(cam, props)
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(num_images):
        try:
            image = cam.retrieveBuffer()
        except PyCapture2.Fc2error as fc2Err:
            print('Error retrieving buffer : %s' % fc2Err)
            continue

        if i == 0:
            video.AVIOpen(filename, framerate)

        video.append(image)
    end = time.time()
    seconds = end - start
    checking_fps = num_images / seconds
    print('Checking fps : %.2f' % checking_fps)
    logging.info('Checking fps : %.2f' % checking_fps)
        # print('Appended image %d...' % i)
    end = time.time()
    seconds = end - start
    check_fps = num_images / seconds

    print('Checking fps : %.2f' % check_fps)
    logging.info('Checking fps : %.2f' % check_fps)

    print('Appended {} images to {} file: {}...'.format(num_images, file_format, filename))
    logging.info('Appended {} images to {} file: {}...'.format(num_images, file_format, filename))
    video.close()
```

I don't understand why the computer sometimes records at 25fps and other times records at 15fps. I would expect the computer to record consistently.

Comment: computer has to run many other programs at the same time. If some programs use more CPU then other programs can't do all on time

Comment: You may find this article useful https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: Thanks, threading the camera operations worked.